# Experience invoking BlueMix Push from Mainframe?

Tags: push-notification, mainframe, connectivity, hybrid, ibm-cloud

Does anyone out there have experience using BlueMix push notification invoked from code written & deployed on Z enterprise (Zos)?  What were the basic coding & connectivity components you used?

Comment: You should try asking your technical staff. If they can't help, I'm sure IBM will be happy to provide examples of how to do this. I'd be surprised if they don't have a support community, and even if they don't there are other routes to ask them. This question as it stands is not a good fit for SO, and will  probably be put on Hold.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier than you think.

BlueMix Push has a REST API, so you can use any development tool capable of sending an HTTP request. In our case, we do it with a simple Java app that runs perfectly fine on z/OS, so long as you have network connectivity to the outside world. If you're not into Java, it could be done in C/C++ or even with a scripted utility like Curl or WGET.

Most sites will have some sort of HTTP Proxy and firewall, so you'll need to  route your HTTP request through these layers, and this is a good reason to write the code in Java, since it's drop-dead simple. Oracle documents it here: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/connecting.html%20here), but you can also just search StackOverflow for plenty of examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is even possible. I'm not a z/OS expert by any stretch but I'm guessing you won't find a suitable compiled binary for that architecture.